# Is it possible? Right-Click in Finder folder should launch a vi editor in that folder

Tags: finder, text-editor, vi, contextual-menu

I often find myself wanting to use the vi editor (vim) to add a text file in an open finder window (directory).

I strongly dislike using TextEdit since it often mangles my text file.

Currently I need to launch vi from the Dock, write my file, but then ask for a save with a filename that needs all of the path from my home directory.

Thanks

Comment: I think it may be possible, but I'm not following the instructions for ["Creating a Custom Quick Action" using the `Automator` app](https://osxdaily.com/2021/08/05/how-create-custom-quick-actions-mac/). Maybe you can do something with this? If so, post a good answer & I'll vote for it :)  In the meantime, I'm going to try using `bindkey` & zsh to do this with a keyboard sequence.

Comment: If you are using vi(m) which is keyboard oriented then why to use GUI file manager like Finder? For example there is [vifm](https://vifm.info) - a file manager with curses interface, which provides Vim-like environment. One can do everything from keyboard and using shortcuts familiar from vi(m).

Comment: Thanks to both. Very good points. Well in my way of working I often use the Finder to navigate through complex directory trees full of files and do so quicker than via cd and ls commands in the shell. Then finally when I found my target I would like to open a vi window there. Maybe Found a solution and will post it as a reply :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so is the following:

1. in the Finder menubar go to View and select "Show Path Bar" and at the bottom of the Finder window you will have a chain of directory icons for the current directory.
2. Right click on the last directory icon (you could do it also on any
   of the previous) and choose "Open in Terminal".
3. You will now have a shell open at the desired location and you can
   launch vi from it (or any other shell command you might need).